# Most efficient and scaleable way to match 2 text columns

Tags: sql, pandas

I currently have a rather hairy SQL query which matches 2 text columns using first a simple LIKE and then a regex.  The approach works fine but as it runs on a task queue I'm finding that my processing speed is becoming limited by the db.

So, given I'd like to parallelise the task and run it on a task queue, is there a better (ie faster, more scaleable) to do this than using SQL?

Comment: Please provide a sample data, and show your expected output https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Wen Here's a helpful tip... you can type `[mvce]`, and it will expand. :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ wow , did not notice that :-), learn it :-)

Comment: This isn't so much a code problem, i'm asking for ideas.  There's no code i could post that would be useful